# Spring Boot @RestController no respond

Tags: java, jquery, rest, spring-boot

I'm starting with Spring and `REST` application. Currently, I'm developing one application on my own and I stuck.

The app is divided just like standard Spring Boot project. All of the controllers are contained in `web` package.
One of "standard" controller is responsible for handling `HTTP` request and returning an `HTML` website. I have added a `REST` controller which should respond to `POST` request from the first controller, but I receive a `404` error.

How it looks like in code?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserRestController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST,  consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, Errors errors) {
        AjaxUser response = new AjaxUser();

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            response.message = errors.getAllErrors().stream().map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);

        }

        response.setUser(userService.getUserById(Integer.getInteger(userId).intValue()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);

    }

    private class AjaxUser {
        private User user;
        private String message;

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User { id:" + user.getId() + ", Name: " + user.getName() + ", surname: " + user.getSurname() + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

From .js file I send a ajax query which should trigger a rest controller, here is the code:

```
function sendUserId(id) {
    var user = {};
    user["userId"] = id;

    console.log("USER: ", user);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/users/user",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (user) {

            var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                + JSON.stringify(user, null, 4) + "</pre>";

            console.log("SUCCESS : ", user);

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                + e.responseText + "</pre>";

            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

`userId` is taken from a html by jQuery, `console.log` show existing and right value.

**Note:** There exist a standard user `@Controller` which is responsible for displaying a user list, it works, problem appear during sending a user id to `REST` controller. It behaves just like the `REST` controller doesn't exist and browser return `404 status response`. Btw, page use a Spring Secure to login and so on.

Could someone help?

BR Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem based on function arguments, REST controller should take String argument and next parse it to JSON object, the response should be String too. Topic can be closed, thanks all to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is looking to have a request parameter that you are missing in the js requesting url

```
/users/user?userId=1
```

Comment: I check a lot of possibilities, but still no result. Do you have any idea how to rebuild my js file which should sent mentioned request parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a user by id like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
User user = userService.findById(id);

if (user == null) {
return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So your rest entry point is /users/userid, eg: /users/1

Found this from the post [Spring MVC RESTFul Web Service CRUD Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/spring-mvc-restful-web-service-crud-example.html)